# How do I phrase this restrictive relative clause

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses

X has problems cooperating with certain people. Now I need to refer to these people using a restrictive relative clause, but I can’t seem to find a way to do this… I have thought of the constructions listed below, but when I Google them (searching UK and USA pages), none of them gets any hits at all. Are they really all wrong? If so, what can I use instead?

1. "with whom * fails to cooperate" (e.g. *people with whom X fails to cooperate*)
2. ”with whom * has problems cooperating”
3. "with whom * has cooperation difficulties"
4. "with whom * has cooperation problems"
5. "with whom * finds it difficult to cooperate"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that versions 1 and 5 sounds best. I did an [Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=finds%20it%20difficult%20to%20cooperate%2C%20fails%20to%20cooperate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfinds%20it%20difficult%20to%20cooperate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfails%20to%20cooperate%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfinds%20it%20difficult%20to%20cooperate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfails%20to%20cooperate%3B%2Cc0) and 1 produces the most hits (probably because it's only three words, compared to five words for 5), but most of the references are to people failing to cooperate with the tax service, or governments failing to cooperate with each other.

5 produces more hits that relate to interpersonal problems. here is an example:

> The main problem arises when the new incumbent comes to a parish and finds a voluntary lay reader attached, with whom he finds it difficult to cooperate -*The parish priest at work, Charles R. Forder, 2013*